# Выборка в DOM с кешированием результата

Tags: javascript

Как реализуется функция выборки элементов в DOM, с последующим кешированием?
По сути задача не сложная, создать объект для сохранения результатов и писать туда, но столкнулся с несколькими проблемами, на которые не нашел ответа самостоятельно.
**Вариант 1:**

```
function getDomElem(func) {
  var cache = {};
  // целевой объект поиска передаем в параметре
  return function (target, selector) {
    if (!(selector in cache)) {
      cache[selector] = func.call(target, selector);
    }
    return cache[selector];
    console.log(cache);
  };
}
```

Использование:

```
// сделаем поиск на основе querySelector
var getElem = getDomElem(Document.prototype.querySelector);

var g = getElem(document, 'div');
// получим div как и задумано
var h = getElem(g, 'p');
// ошибка!!!! Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

console.log(g, h)
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
function getDomElem(func) {
  var cache = {};
  return function (selector) {
    if (!(selector in cache)) {
      // хочу сделать объектом поиска текущий объект на котором была вызвана функция
      cache[selector] = func.call(this, selector);
    }
    return cache[selector];
    console.log(cache);
  };
}

var getElem = getDomElem(Document.prototype.querySelector);

var g = document.getElem('div');
// ошибка!!! Uncaught TypeError: document.getElem is not a function
```

Comment: проблема в том. что ты пытаешься использовать одну функцию для разных типов: документа и элемента, у каждого из них есть своя реализация

Comment: @Grundy Посоветуй как можно сделать универсально?

Comment: не сохранять функцию из прототипа, а вызывать ее напрямую из target

Comment: @Grundy в таком случае я лишаюсь возможности использовать другие поисковые методы, наприме `getElementById` и прочие.....

Comment: А зачем они тебе в этом случае, если ты уже используешь querySelector(All)? в который можно передать css селектор в том числе и для id?

Comment: Самый простой вариант, разбить как минимум на две функции: `getElementFromDocument` и `getElementFromElement` и уже внутри них брать функцию из нужного прототипа

Comment: @Grundy  _А зачем они тебе в этом случае_    
Исключительно для универсальности интерфейса

Comment: В твоем случае универсально не получится, потому что ты сам выбираешь откуда брать функцию

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64160/discussion-between-grundy-and-pepel-xd).